# Using a FutureBuilder but then modifying a local value in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-futurebuilder, sembast

I'm trying to get my head around how I should manage reading data from a database in Flutter (or any API/backend).

Without a database and just using state that's local to the widget I'd expect to write something similar to the following. I am printing out a list of strings in a `ListView` and adding a new one when a `FloatingActionButton` is pressed.

```dart
class _ListScreenState extends State<ListScreen> {
  var _myStrings = ["string1", "string2"];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: _myStrings.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return Text(_myStrings[index]);
        }
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () => {
            setState(() {
              _myStrings.add("another string");
            });
        },
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

However, when reading from a database, I've extracted the database logic behind a repository class and so I'm using a FutureBuilder.

```dart
class _ListScreenState extends State<ListScreen> {
  final _repo = FooRepository();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: FutureBuilder(
          future: _repo.getAll(),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.data == null) {
              return const Center(child: Text("Loading..."));
            }
            return ListView<String, String>(
                elements: snapshot.data,
                itemBuilder: (context, element) {
                  return Text(element);
                }
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () => {
          _repo.add("newstring");
        },
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This seems to go against the idea of the flutter widget being reactive to changes in its local state. Am I doing something wrong here? I don't know whether calling `setState()` will cause the `FutureBuilder` to redraw but it also seems wasteful to re-get all the records from the database when one is added. Should/can I hold a copy of the strings locally to the widget and add to both the database but also the local list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using a `FutureBuilder` you should not need to use `setState`, as the actual update of the state, based on the Future's response, will be managed by the `FutureBuilder` itself.

The problem here is that `FutureBuilder` is used when you want to retrieve some data once, but from your example, you would like that once you press your button and a new `String` is added to the `Database`, that the widget displays reactively the new data.
In this case probably you want to use a `StreamBuilder`, which is very similiar to a `FutureBuilder`, but it's used when you want to display some data that can change over time.

With your example, using a `FutureBuilder`, when you add some data to the `Database` the only way to get the new data would be to refetch it via the `_repo.getAll()` method.
This can work if it's what you want, you simply can force a rebuild once the button is pressed, and the `future` will run again.

To answer your final question, if you want you can manage your state locally, in this case, I would suggest to refactor your code, and add some state management logic, for example a simple `Provider`.
There you can initialize your data by calling once `_repo.getAll()`, and in your Widget, you would not use anymore a `FutureBuilder` or `StreamBuilder`, but you would listen to the changes coming from the `Provider`, via a `Consumer`, then when your button is pressed, the `Provider` can add that piece of data to the `object` and your `UI` would see immediately the changes.
I can provide you a simple example:

your provider, that manages the state:

```
class YourDataProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
      bool isLoading = true;
      List<String> myData = [];
    
      Future<void> getAll() async {
        isLoading = true;
        notifyListeners();
    
        myData = await yourAsyncCall();
    
        isLoading = false;
        notifyListeners();
      }
    
      Future<void> add(String value) async {
        isLoading = true;
        notifyListeners();
    
        await yourAddAsyncCall(value);
    
        myData.add(value);
    
        notifyListeners();
      }
    }
```

your UI widget

```
.....
  @override
  void initState() {
    context.read<YourDataProvider>.getAll();
    super.initState();
  }

class _ListScreenState extends State<ListScreen> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    YourDataProvider provider = context.watch<YourDataProvider>;

    return Scaffold(
      body: provider.isLoading
      ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
      : ListView.builder(
        itemCount: provider.myData.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) => Text(provider.myData[index]),
      )
    ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () => provider.add("newstring"),
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

As you can see, the `Provider` will fetch once the data, and then it will hold the state, and once a new `String` is added, it will only submit it to the backend, but it won't be refetching all the data again.

Answer (score 1):

using `future: _repo.getAll()`, setState will recall the api. You need to create a future variable and then put it on `future`.

```dart
class _ListScreenState extends State<ListScreen> {
  final _repo = FooRepository();
  late Future future = _repo.getAll();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: FutureBuilder(
          future: future,
```

More about [Fixing a common FutureBuilder and StreamBuilder problem](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sqE-J8YJnpg)